# testcafe cookies session-cookies

Tags: cookies, automated-tests, session-cookies, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using testcafe to test our site that needs authentication.  Things work fine but I noticed the cookies are not set correctly when I inspect the page during the test.  all the cookie name seems to be in the format of:

```
w|ErNwuuhVT|KEYCLOAK_SESSION|xxx.abc.def|%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Fdomain%2F|jxd35gq0|jxchpvfp
```

which is not the correct format that our site uses when you just browse to the site itself.  why is it pipe delimited? is there a reason why testcafe saves the cookies in that format?  also, the names of the cookies don't match what's expected.  although we can log in its causing some other resources to not load correctly.
another issue that the cookie is supposed to be saved under the domain of ".abc.def" however testcafe saves the cookie in the full domain which would be something like "xxx.abc.def" which also causes problems.  why does testcafe do this? Is it b/c of the hammerhead proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe uses a [URL-rewritten proxy](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead) internally. 
This proxy is forced to handle cookies manually because the URL of the tested website is changed during test execution.
If there are problems related to the process of applying cookies, please report an issue to the [TestCafe repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).

Comment: is it expected that a cookie's name and domain will be changed though when running through testcafe?  if i have a cookie "abc=def" and saved to domain xxxyyy.com, should i expect the same cookie to show up when I inspect the page when running in testcafe?

Comment: Yes it's expected. TestCafe processes all cookies, so they appear in modified format. As you already mentioned, it's the result `testcafe-hammerhead` proxy mechanism which modifies the cookies for our internal services. Besides, every single test runs with clean cookies, thus each test is independent from another test's state. In a general case, you do not need to inspect the cookies, if you have some specific issue please report it.

Comment: so just to understand this a little better.  if i go to a site like abcxyz.com and it sets a cookie.  hammerhead will take the cookie and rewrite it in its own format.  and when i navigate around, it will take the reformatted cookie, format it back to what abcxyz.com is expecting and send it back?  is that a good description?

Comment: No. The cookie processing algorithm is too complex. It includes two separate parts: for client cookies (changed via `document.cookie=<value>`) and server cookies (changed via `Set-Cookie` header). 
The main idea - store the final cookie state on server side (instead of a browser way - store the cookie state on the client side). 
The mechanism is very complex and the best way to fix the problem is to create an issue in the TestCafe repository with a full example.

Comment: Since version 1.19.0 TestCafe ships with flexible cross-browser methods that allow one to manage browser cookies even if the `HttpOnly` flag is specified.
Follow the [link](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403873/reference/test-api/testcontroller/getcookies) to see an example in TestCafe documentation of how to set and retrieve cookies from the specified URLs.